# Java: Why doesn't this JPanel paint properly?

Tags: graphics, jpanel, multidimensional-array, graphics2d, repaint

I have a 2D array. I want each pixel to be represented by a total of four in the actual image. I've tried various piece of code but none seem to work and I don't really understand how it works either.

So far I have:

```
panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Rectangle rect = g.getClipBounds();
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                for (int i = 0; i < m.width(); i++) {
                    for (int j=0; j < m.height(); j++) {
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                        g.fillRect(j*4, i*4, 4, 4);
                    }
                }
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        panel.repaint();
```

Where am I going wrong? The area stays completely grey with no colour!

Answer (score 0):

While overriding `paint()` is not the worst thing to do, I highly recommend overriding `paintComponent()` instead. Also, you must call `super.paint()` *prior* to doing your drawing using the `Graphics` object, not afterwards. It just scraps all of your work that way.

Also, I don't know if you did this or not, since you don't have it in your code, but make sure to add the panel to the `JFrame` or whatever window class you are using so it will actually show up. I hope this helps.